# How to stream the linux framebuffer as video over http

Tags: linux, embedded, webserver, camera, framebuffer

I have an embedded linux system (yocto based) with a framebuffer UI (no X11) and a running web server.

Now I'm asking how to "mirror" the screen contents to a web page. Think of it like a web cam, except the stream is not coming from a camera, but from `/dev/fb0`.

Sounds like a quite obvious thing to do, but my web search didn't throw any matches. Do you have an idea on how to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

The linux framebuffer video is available in ffmpeg via the [`fbdev`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#fbdev) device.

```
> ffprobe -f fbdev -i '/dev/fb0'                                                                           
[fbdev @ 0x2308100] w:1920 h:1080 bpp:32 pixfmt:bgra fps:25/1 bit_rate:1658880000
[fbdev @ 0x2308100] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #0, fbdev, from '/dev/fb0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1673953008.518392, bitrate: 1658880 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (BGRA / 0x41524742), bgra, 1920x1080, 1658880 kb/s, 25 fps, 1000k tbr, 1000k tbn
```

That should tell you some metadata about the video source, useful for testing. Replace `ffprobe` with `ffmpeg` to do the usual video transcoding:

```
> ffmpeg -f fbdev -i '/dev/fb0' -f matroska -crf 0 -filter:v 'scale=-1:720' - | mpv
```

That will send the encoded video stream to `stdout`, which should be played by `mpv` after a few seconds of buffering. If your headless server is accessible via SSH, you can reuse this pipe technique and do:

```
ssh server ffmpeg -f fbdev -i '/dev/fb0' -f matroska -crf 0 -filter:v 'scale=-1:720' - | mpv
```

This must be run from a machine with a GUI and a video player installed (`mpv` in the example above) which has SSH access to `server`. Alternatively, the video stream can be exposed over HTTP. Looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24017930/how-to-stream-with-ffmpeg-via-http-protocol) answer, for example, you could do this:

```
ffmpeg -f fbdev -i '/dev/fb0' -f mp4 -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov -listen 1 http://localhost:8080/
```

That makes ffmpeg a one-shot webserver, where you can point your favorite video player to, e.g. `vlc http://localhost:8080/`. Your browser might insist to downloading that file, which will probably require wrapping the url in some HTML.

Making a proper streaming web-server is a larger topic, and probably difficult to get right if you intend to have many visitors and support various devices. The topic seems to have been [answered](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/25390/ffmpeg-live-stream-into-a-browser-video-tag-localhost-only) [multiple](https://dev.to/tejasvi2/rtsp-stream-to-web-browser-using-ffmpeg-1cb) [times](https://superuser.com/questions/630286/ffmpeg-to-remote-server-live-streaming-with-segments), but for other video sources.

I hope this will take you a step in the right direction.

> Note: If you want to mess around with your framebuffer content while you're testing this, you can issue `cat /dev/urandom >/dev/fb0` and `cat /dev/zero >/dev/fb0`

Comment: I have edited my question with more references and the simples ffmpeg-webserver trick I could find. I hope this is satisfactory.

Comment: @AdminBee the real *new and hardly covered* part of the question in this was how to take video stream from framebuffer with ffmpeg; it's perfectly answered. How to use ffmpeg to stream video is entirely different and widely covered topic. Actually better is to reduce the scope of the question for it to only contain one question, than to extend the answer to cover both parts and making it partially redundant.